# how to prove this greedy algorithm as optimal: rod connection

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Here is the problem:

Given an array represents the lengths of rods on the table. Every time pick two rods and connect them and get a new rod. Do this until there is only one rod on the table.
The cost of a connection is the sum of two rods' lengths, for example, connect 2 with 3 will get a 5 rod and cost 5.
What is the minimum cost connection strategy?

Greedy: every time pick the shortest two and put the connected new rod back to the table.

Example:

[1,2,3,4,5] , pick 1 and 2 cost 3 [3,3,4,5], pick 3 and 3 cost 6 [4,5,6], pick 4 and 5 cost 9 [6,9], pick 6 and 9 cost 15. So that the total cost is 33.

We can't simply say that, total times of connection is the same n-1 so that every time picking smallest two will give a final minimum cost. Because every picking will change the future, like picking 1+2 and picking 2+4 will result in two different sets of rods for the next step.

How can I prove this greedy will get minimum cost?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, the cost will always be same - because, `(a + b) + c = a + (b + c) = a + (c + b) = (a + c) + b = a + b + c`; i.e - whatever order you are using to connect the rods, the cost will always be same - according to your definition of connection cost.

Comment: After connection, you will get a new rod. For (a, b, c), if you pick a & b first, you will get a new rod (a + b) and cost a + b. Then pick (a + b) & c so that cost a + b + c and there is only one rod on the table now. Total cost is 2a + 2b + c. Similarly, the other two strategies will get 2a + b + 2c and a + 2b + 2c total costs. @Muntasir

Comment: oh, now i got it - what you are trying to minimize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is similar to a proof that Huffman'c code is optimal.

There's a binary tree corresponding to each strategy. It contains all initial rods in its leaves and inner vertices correspond to connection operations.

One can see that the cost of connecting the rods for a fixed tree is the sum of `a[v] * depth[v]` over all leaves `v`, where `a[v]` is the length of the initial rod and `depth[v]` is the depth of the leave. It's the case because each rod takes part in a connection exactly `depth[v]` times.

We need to show that there exists an optimal strategy such that its tree has two shortest rods as siblings.

Let assume that `T` is an optimal tree. Let's sort it's leaves by their depths (in non-strictly decreasing order). If the two shortest rods are the first two leaves, we're done. Otherwise, let's keep swapping them with their left sibling (which is at least as long as them) until they get into the first two positions. When we swap 2 leaves `u` and `v`, the cost change is `-depth[u] * a[u] - depth[v] * a[v] + depth[u] * a[v] + depth[v] * a[u]` = `(depth[v] - depth[u]) * (a[u] - a[v])`. The first term is non-positive (as the leaves were sorted by their height) and the second term is non-negative (as `a[u] >= a[v]`). Thus, the cost change is negative or zero.

Hence, there exists an optimal tree where two shortest rods are siblings. It means that there's an optimal strategy where we connect these two rods before we do anything else.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot! :D